# How to do scrolling in j2me canvas?

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I have created a sample application where I want to do scrolling, but I am not able to achieve the desired output.

I have tried the following code inside paint method >>>>>

```
g.translate(x,y);
```

and passing the value for variable 'y' in keydown and keyup event.

Can anyone help me out to do this?

Comment: most likely there's a bug in your code. If you show code you use in Canvas#keyPressed and in Canvas#paint, it will be easier to tell. Also, how do you test your app - do you use emulator? do you write log messages from code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried with decrementing the value of Y in keyUP and calling `repaint()` method also do same with keyDown but now the value of Y will be decrementing and call `repaint()` method.

Use the `g.translate(x, changingYvalue);`

try this.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way (though memory intensive) is to use MutableImage, and draw it with negative y coordinates.

Mutable image is just a new Image(w,h).
Then you get its Graphics context, using `myImage.getGraphics()`, and draw with this Graphics object. It serves as an off-screen buffer.

Than in paint(Graphics g), you call:

```
g.drawImage(0,y,...);
```

where you loop decreasing y on each system call to paint.
(don't block paint! - each call is one frame, and you're doing frame by frame animation
do the animation loop from another thread, where you decrease y, than call repaint(), and sleep).

Answer (score 0):

I think that the scrollbar should be drawn inside the `paint` method. And you implement the `keyReleased` method when clicking the arrow of the scrollbar. To implement the `scrolling` I would prefer call `repaint();` and I will manage the `paint` method with boolean or some other type of private `variable`.